# I got an invalid Python SDK When I use Pycharm on my Mac

Tags: python, sdk, system, interpreter

I am newbie in PyCharm and Python. Now when I ran the script on my mac, PyCharm said *you have an invalid interpreter*. And I got the error as below.

Also, I would like to configure the system interpreter. However, another error appears, "Invalid python SDK" - Cannot set up a python SDK Python 3.10 The SDK seems invalid. Does anyone help me out?

> /Users/abc/PycharmProjects/Giraffe/venv/bin/python "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py" --cmd-line --multiproc --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 49936 --file /Users/abc/PycharmProjects/My1stProject/MyProject1.py
> dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
>   Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
>   Reason: image not found